# How to get verification code using css or xpath in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

```
<body>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="mailview" style="margin-right:18px;">
<p>Dear  MohanNimmala First,</p>
<p>Thank you for registering with MediAngels!</p>
<p>
<p>
Verification Code:
<b> 95527</b>
```

Can someone help me to get verification code as 95527 from above 
using xpath or css?

I am using following xpath=`html/body/div[1]/div/div/p[4]/b`

[image]

Comment: Your HTML is missing a bit (no <html>, no closing </body>...), please edit it to represent the exact output. Also some indenting would be nice. Make it as easy for people to help you.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="mailview" style="margin-right:18px;">
<p>Dear  MohanNimmala First,</p>
<p>Thank you for registering with MediAngels!</p>
<p>
<p>
Verification Code:
<b> 95527</b>
<br/>

Comment: Please edit the post instead of commenting on it. Also (again) you are missing HTML. Where's the rest that follows after </b><br />

Learn a bit more about Stack Overflow here http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting yourself up for problems later if you nest the 'verification code' so deep in the HTML. When someone changes the layout/html, the test is very likely to fail.

I suggest giving the b tag an ID and to use that ID in your selector. Your test will be more resilient.

Add the HTML attribute to the b-tag:

```
Verification Code:
<b id="verification-code"> 95527</b>
....
```

And the xpath

```
//*[@id='verification-code']
```

---

The issue with your xpath is probably that you're missing a slash at the beginning. One slash starts from the root, two slashes starts anywhere.

```
/html/body/div/div/div/p[4]/b
```

Comment: Hi Deef,
thanks for your Answer. i tried with following xpath but still not working 

Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Verification Code:']")).getText();
or
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='verification-code']")).getText();

Comment: Did you change the html output accordingly? See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Based only on the HTML snippet posted in question, you may want to try the following XPath :

```
//p[contains(text(), 'Verification Code')]/b
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Deef& Har, for your answers below code works to extract value from innterhtml tags

`driver.switchTo().frame("rendermail");
WebElement OTP=driver.findElement(By.tagName("b"));
System.out.println(OTP.getText());`